# float and margin-top

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="foot">
        <div id="one">
            <span id="aaa" class="test">aaa</span>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <span id="bbb" class="test">bbb</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


#home {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#logo {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#foot {
   height: 200px;
}

#one {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: red;
}

#two {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;    
}

.test {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

why in this example float: left doesnt working? and why margin-top set position of #home and not of parents?

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/tLuTS/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating doesn't work in your example because you need to float both elements that you want on the same line.

So I've updated your example with #one and #two floated left. Also added some IE float fixes. http://jsfiddle.net/tLuTS/11/

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve using `margin-top`.

Comment: why margin-top in .class doesnt work? margin-left is ok.  
why this set position of #body, and not of #foot?

Comment: The class is applied to a span which is not block level. So the margin's won't work. Is this better? http://jsfiddle.net/tLuTS/13/

Comment: Do you want the text to be spaced away from the top of the red and blue boxes? You need to change the padding not the margin. Like so – http://jsfiddle.net/tLuTS/14/

Answer (score 1):

Both elements need to be floated, and the second one should have `clear:both` set.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tLuTS/12/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just add this

```
#one {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: red;
    float:left;
}
```

Here is the updated version on [jsfiddle.net.](http://jsfiddle.net/AEJBY/)

Comment: thanks, and why margin-top in .class doesnt work? margin-left is ok. why this set position of #body, and not of #foot?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your inline CSS "test" . For Span Id="bbb", there are two CSS define one is "test" and other is "two". Priority of "test" is more so float is not working .

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want `one` and `two` both in the `footer`. So you have to apply

```
float: left;
```

to `one` as well. About the margins: I can only see margins applied to the text with yellow background. These are `<span>`s, so inline elements. Make these block level elements, like `<p>`, for the margin to have effect.